# Removing engine thinking (variations) PGN comments in Arena Chess

Tags: engines, arena

I setup a position in Arena. Then lets engine vs engine plays it after pressing 'Demo' button.

The problem is Arena put engine thinking as well into the moves list. (in green font). Check the screenshot.

[image]

How can I remove those marked in green font? I only want main moves (no variations or engine thinking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Options → Appearance → Movelist and under **View** uncheck "Show comments in the movelist". This should hide the engine thinking variations.

Alternatively, you can right-click in a move → Display → Comments.